# VBA Type Mismatch Issue

Tags: excel, vba, navbar, vba7, vba6

```vb
Sub Delete_Specific_Columns()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ActiveSheet
sh.Columns("B:D,I:AZ,BC:BJ,BO:EQ").Delete
End Sub
```

Keep getting a type mismatch error.

Answer (score 1):

The `Columns` property doesn't accept multiple column addresses (like B:D) or using commas to join multiple areas, it only accepts a single  number or column letter name (like "D" or "BC"). If you want to use a complex address, use the `Range` property instead:

```vb
Sub Delete_Specific_Columns()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ActiveSheet
sh.Range("B:D,I:AZ,BC:BJ,BO:EQ").Delete Shift:=xlShiftToLeft
End Sub
```